# Mono 2.8 (4.0 .net) Method that Throws NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, .net, linq, mono

I'm using mono for the first time today on Debian and I'm getting an error when loading my .dll.  I'm using Linq to SQL

The error states: Missing method .ctor in assembly, type System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAtribute Can't find custom attr constructor image.

So I then tried the MoMa tool and I show these errors

Calling Method  Method that Throws NotImplementedException

```
void .ctor ()                       void DataContext..ctor (string, MappingSource)
void .ctor (string)                 void DataContext..ctor (string, MappingSource)
void .ctor (string, MappingSource)      void DataContext..ctor (string, MappingSource)
void LoadAll ()                     void DataContext.set_CommandTimeout (int)
```

this is from my code

```
    public SwitchDataDataContext(string connection) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }
```

So, I can live without the timeout but the others I believe are the constructor for the connection string.

I'm compiling in VS 4.5.2 if that matters then bringing it over to Debian.

Any ideas other than recoding to ado.net
Thanks
andre

Comment: Mono 2.8 is obsolete, and you should use 3.* now. http://www.mono-project.com/download/

Comment: Is there a way to see the current version? I just installed it. I thought it was 2.8. Could be wrong.

Comment: looks like you are correct. funny thing is I downloaded it from their webpage yesterday. I would still like to know how to verify version. tks

Comment: Use `mono --version` ;)

Comment: any chance you all know how to fix my new issue?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630540/mono-on-debian-7-linq-to-sql-connection-string-object-reference-not-set-to-an-in

Comment: Consider closing your existing questions before  posting more. Or your reputation is going to be hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the wrong version. Upgrade to the newest fixed it.