# Mono on Debian 7 Linq To SQL String object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, sql, linux, linq, mono

hi I'm new to Linux and mono. I am using Mono 3.6 and Debian 7.6

I keep getting object reference not set to an instance of an object. I use the same code that I compile on windows with VS 2013 and it works fine.

```
  string connstring = string.Format
("Data Source={0},{1};Initial Catalog={2};User ID={3};Password={4};Application Name={5};Connect Timeout=120",
   IP, Port, database, Username, Password, InstanceID);

 settings = new ConnectionStringSettings("sqlServer", 
                                       connstring, "System.Data.SqlClient");


 using (data = new SwitchDataDataContext(settings.ConnectionString)){
                   BlockList.Clear();
                    foreach (var item in data.BlockLists)
                    {// so this works
                        if (BlockList.ContainsKey(item.TN) == false)
                            BlockList.TryAdd(item.TN, item.TN);
                        }
// this is where it crashes
  var custs = data.CustomerGateways.Where(p => p.isEnabled == true);

}
```

When I call the code it throws an exception.

Any idea what could be wrong?

works fine on Windows.

I wrote the exception to the screen. DbLinq.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedMetaType+c__Iterator0.MoveNext() [0x00000] in :0 at System.Collections.Generic.List System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaAssociation   .AddEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out.  In the Linq's Map for all the tables you have joins. Those joins need to be Internal not Public. I've done this in the past when I have to serialize the data.  Public for some reason causes like a looping of PK's.

Either way change the thing to internal in the Linq Map and it works.

Comment: too many issues using mono. Lazy loading doesn't work at all. I moved to EF and that too has issues. I get errors saying the dataset is already open. only fix is to do .tolist().. i'm thinking of moving to ADO

Comment: Please accept yours as the answer to close this question. EF was designed completely without Mono in mind, and Mono evolves in a similar way. So NHibernate style open source projects work better than EF on Mono. Since Microsoft turns to work with Mono (for ASP.NET vNext's sake), we should see more bugs fixed in both in the coming weeks.